# Flash CS 5.5 Actionscript 3 - Buttons appearing on all frames

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a program that lets the user go to various functions, that all work. However when I use the music player function that i made the play and stop buttons remain on screen when i click back to return to the menu of options. Here is my code:

```
play_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickhandler);
stop_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickhandler);
function clickhandler(event:MouseEvent): void{ 

swapChildren(play_button, stop_button)
}
```

The music file is embedded in the buttons.

The following error appears every time:

> ```
> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
>   at SmartHouse_Scene1_fla::MainTimeline/frame10()
>   at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
>   at SmartHouse_Scene1_fla::MainTimeline/fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_27()
> ```

It should be noted that the error only occurs when the music has been played. I can go to the page and leave without the problem if i dont touch the play or stop button. If anyone could help i would really appreciate it.

Comment: What's in swapChildren? What's the relationship between this code and playing the music?

Answer (score 0):

if reading this correct the sounds are inside the button on the timeline, are you using buttons or movieclips, make sure that frame 27 exist on the movieClip timline.

```
              //you can use//  myMovieClip.visble = false;
              example:

              play_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickhandler);
              function clickhandler(event:MouseEvent): void{ 
              stage.myMovieClip.visible = false; // the name of your button clip
              }
```